# Import txt file but dim is only 1

Tags: r

I want to import a txt file so I did the following in R:

```
breast <- read.table("breastdata.txt",header=F)
```

But when I check the dimension of this, I get 569 1. So it behaves like it has one column while there are multiple. How can I separate these columns in R?

This is how my data looks like:
"Diagnosis" "radius" "texture" "perimeter" "area" "smoothness" "compactness" "concavity" "concave points" "symmetry" "fractal dimension"
"842302" "M" 17.99 10.38 122.8 1001 0.1184 0.2776 0.3001 0.1471 0.2419 0.07871
"842517" "M" 20.57 17.77 132.9 1326 0.08474 0.07864 0.0869 0.07017 0.1812 0.05667

Comment: can you give an example of the structure of the data in the text file? is it comma delimited? tabbed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to specify the appropriate separator.

Open the text file using a text editor and identify the separator (the character that specifies the next column within each row), after which you'll be able to either:

- Use a wrapper function that has this separator, along with other common arguments* assigned.
- Specify the arguments yourself.

* Arguments are variables you provide to a function that specify how it should behave. In the following examples sep="," or header=FALSE are examples of arguments.

The manual way of setting the arguments:

```
#Columns separated by a ","
read.table("breastdata.txt",header=FALSE,
         sep=",")  

#Columns separated by a ";"
read.table("breastdata.txt",header=FALSE,
         sep=";")
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the wrapper functions that automatically sets some of the parameters of read.table to reduce some of your work:

```
# Common European format: "," as the decimal point, ";" as the column separator;
read.csv2("breastdata.txt",header=FALSE)     # Which would be (almost) equal to read.table("breastdata.txt",header=FALSE,sep=",")

# Common US format: "." as the decimal point, "," as the column separator;
read.csv("breastdata.txt",header=FALSE)
```

These basically call read.table and override the default arguments, read ?read.table to see all the arguments you can manually set or see what wrappers exist.

EDIT:
Copying the data to a text file and specifying the space separator works?

```
dt = read.table("test.txt",header=TRUE,sep=" ")
dt
           Diagnosis radius texture perimeter area smoothness compactness concavity     concave.points symmetry fractal.dimension
842302         M  17.99   10.38     122.8 1001    0.11840     0.27760    0.3001        0.14710   0.2419           0.07871
842517         M  20.57   17.77     132.9 1326    0.08474     0.07864    0.0869        0.07017   0.1812           0.05667
```

Comment: There is no seperationsign, it's just a little bit of space between. So I tried: sep=" ". But then I get an error..

Comment: Could you copy the first few rows into the question?

Comment: @Silke The data you provided does not give me an error, are all rows complete? If not try to add fill=TRUE to data.table to fill empty values with NAs.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see it, but exactly that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set a `dec=","` or `dec="."` in order for R to parse the decimal numbers, you have on your dataset as is. Also try setting `header=TRUE` and see what happens.

Example:

```
#Decimal separation
read.table("breastdata.txt",header=TRUE,
         dec=".")
```

Try to edit your question, structuring your data properly so we have a clear view of it and then post the errors you get, reflecting the suggestions made etc.